# Can you explain the meaning of "s'y" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, locutions

This is my first time writing here.

I can't understand what the pronoun ***s'y*** is doing before ***devait*** and not after it.

> *Antoine de Rebours (...) s'y devait connaître en humilité.*
> François Mauriac, *Blaise Pascal et sa sœur Jacqueline*, VI.

Thank you!

Comment: Bienvenu dans la communauté !

Answer (score 3):

***S'y devait*** + **infinitive** is a rare variant, usually literary, of ***devait s'y*** + **infinitive**. There is no change in meaning.

Here are examples of this inversion. The first one is not literary but colloquial. The second one is more complex, ***s'y devait le moins attendre*** is used while the usual order would be ***devait s'y attendre le moins***.

> Camus, en accrochant sa première branche pour se rétablir, commença par dégringoler de son chêne, de pas très haut heureusement, et sur ses pattes encore. C’était la revanche de Touegueule : **il s’y devait attendre**, mais il pensait que l’autre s’attaquerait lui aussi à une branche de son « assetotte ».
>
> Louis Pergaud, [La guerre des boutons](https://www.atramenta.net/lire/oeuvre26214-chapitre-24.html), 1912.

> *Cette Déesse inconstante
>
> Se mit alors en l'esprit
>
> De voir un homme se pendre ;
>
> Et celui qui se pendit
>
> **S'y devait le moins attendre**.*
>
> Jean de la Fontaine, *[Le Trésor et les deux Hommes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Tr%C3%A9sor_et_les_Deux_Hommes)*, 1678

Comment: Merci! It's a good answer!